# how to interpret interpret timeit command in Python

Tags: python, time, ipython, generator, python-2.x

For example I have a list:

```
L=[-13, -24, -21, -3, -23, -15, -14, -27, -13, -12]
```

1. if type in `%timeit -n 10 myList = [item for item in L if item < 15]`
   The output is `10 loops, best of 3: 1.25 µs per loop`
2. if I type `myGen = (item for item in L if item < 15)`
   The output is `1000000 loops, best of 3: 561 ns per loop`

I don't understand in case 2, why a generator takes 1000000 loops rather than 10 loops? And what does "best of 3" mean? And how can I work out the total seconds it takes for each commond, like 10*1.25=12.5 us for case 1?

Comment: "best of 3" is from the number of repeats: -r N, --repeat=N "how many times to repeat the timer (default 3)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't include the `-n` argument to `%timeit` in your second example, so ipython varies the number of repetitions based on how long a trial-run takes; the faster the piece of code being tested, the more iterations are done to get a more accurate per-iteration time value.

Moreover, the tests are run several times to try and minimise external factors (for example, when your OS just happened to schedule a disk buffer flush and everything else becomes a little bit slower). This is where the 'best of 3' comes in; the tests were run 3 times in a row and the best timings were picked.

See the [`%timeit` magic command documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit), which includes these options and their default behaviour:

> `-n<N>`: execute the given statement `<N>` times in a loop. If this value is not given, a fitting value is chosen.
>
> `-r<R>`: repeat the loop iteration `<R>` times and take the best result. Default: 3

Your first example *does* use `-n 10` so it was run just 10 times.

Because creating a *generator* object with a generator expression is near-instant, ipython can execute the loop way more often than executing a list comprehension (which has to execute the `for` loop and produce a list object with all the results *there and then*).  Remember that a generator expression does not do **any** work until you drive iteration.

If you wanted to compare how long a generator expression takes to produce the same results as a list comprehension, you'd have to actually iterate. You could pass the expression to a `list()` call to actually produce a list too:

```
%timeit -n 10 myGen = (item for item in L if item < 15); list(myGen)
```

This'll be slower as a generator has a little more overhead than a list comprehension:

```
In [1]: L=[-13, -24, -21, -3, -23, -15, -14, -27, -13, -12]

In [2]: %timeit -n 10 myList = [item for item in L if item < 15]
10 loops, best of 3: 1.29 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit -n 10 myGen = (item for item in L if item < 15); list(myGen)
10 loops, best of 3: 1.72 µs per loop
```

Note that you *have* to re-create the generator each test iteration because generators can produce their output just once.